# Predefined searches with helm-occur

Tags: helm, occur

Is there a way to have predefined helm-occur searches so that I can then bind them to a key?

I have some frequently and hard-to-type searches that would benefit from this.

*(I used to do this easily with `helm-swoop` but it seems to be abandoned)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how `helm-swoop` worked, but you can do this:

```
(defun call-helm-occur (query)
  "Passes QUERY to helm-occur using `isearch-string'."
  (let ((isearch-string query))
    (call-interactively 'helm-occur-from-isearch)))
```

`helm-occur-from-isearch` pulls its input from the variable `isearch-string`, so use `let` binding to set this variable.